# Populating or aggregating inside virtuals for mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I had a old virtual which is used by almost around 100 queries,

```
AssignmentSchema.virtual('m1s', {
  ref: 'M1',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'm2Id',
  options: { match: { entityType: 'm2entity' } },
});
```

now i had to add another mapping layer between this 2 models, M1M2mapping

i want to fetch mapping inside the mongoose virtual and return the mapped documents as a direct array!

To simplify my question, i want populate inside virtuals, will it work or any alternative solutions that can take its place?

i couldnot find any kind of aggregation, i also tried linking virtuals to no avial,

```
AssignmentSchema.virtual('m1s', {
  ref: 'mappingmodel',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'mappingid',
  justOne: false,
  options: { match: { entityType: 'mappingentity' } },
});

AssignmentSchema.virtual('populatedM1s', {
  ref: 'M1',
  localField: 'm1s.m1Id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: false,
  options: { match: { active: true } },
});
```